# How do I get Nagios plugins to work?

Tags: python, monitoring, nagios, ganglia

I have installed Nagios successfully, and added the following services:

`nano /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/services.cfg`

```
define host {
    use                 linux-server
    host_name           dcctst1e
    address             160.81.38.74
}

define host {
    use                 linux-server
    host_name           dcctst1f
    address             160.81.38.75
}

define host {
    use                 linux-server
    host_name           dcctst1g
    address             160.81.38.76
}

define hostgroup {
    hostgroup_name ganglia-servers
    alias   nagios server
    members *
}

define servicegroup {
  servicegroup_name ganglia-metrics
  alias Ganglia Metrics
}

define command {
  command_name check_ganglia
  command_line $USER1$/check_ganglia.py -h $HOSTNAME$ -m $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$ -o $ARG4$
}

define service{
        use                             ganglia-service
        service_description             Free Memory
        check_command                   check_ganglia!mem_free!200!50!1
        contact_groups admins
}

define service{
        use                             ganglia-service
        service_description             load_one
        check_command                   check_ganglia!load_one!4!5!0
        contact_groups admins
}
define service{
        use                             ganglia-service
        service_description             disk_free
        check_command                   check_ganglia!disk_free!40!50!0
        contact_groups admins
}
define service{
        use                             ganglia-service
        service_description             yarn.NodeManagerMetrics.AvailableGB
        check_command                   check_ganglia!yarn.NodeManagerMetrics.AvailableGB!8!4!1
        contact_groups admins
}
define service{
        use                             ganglia-service
        service_description             Temperature
        check_command                   check_ganglia!!8!4!1
        contact_groups admins
}
```

As shown in the screenshot below, some of the relevant plugins (like, `disk_free`, `load_one`, etc are present in `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/`. But, when checking the service `disk_free`, it gives error:

`$ python check_ganglia.py`

```
Usage: check_ganglia -h|--host= -m|--metric= -w|--warning= -c|critical= [-o|--opposite=] [-s|--server=] [-p|--port=]
```

`$ python check_ganglia.py -h dcctst1f -m disk_free -w 40 -c 50 -o 1`

```
CHECKGANGLIA UNKNOWN: Error while getting value"no element found: line1, column 0"
```

Why is this? What can I do to make it work?

I am also attaching a screenshot of the web version of the services; I expected 3 of the services to be green as their plugins are installed.

[image]

**P.S.**

Since the error in Nagios web says:

> (No output on stdout) stderr: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ganglia.py: line 4: import command not found

I commented the 4th line of `check_ganglia.py`, which was `import sys`. When I ran the command again, it gives the error:

> NameError: name `sys` is not defined

So, clearly, I cannot comment out `import sys`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have on the first line of your script `check_ganglia.py` something like `#!/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: Yes, the exact first line is `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: So, `python check_ganglia.py` works without problem. What about `./check_ganglia.py`? Is it working?`

Comment: @Rohlik Yes, it is working. Gives the same output as that by `python check_ganglia.py`.

Comment: Can you try run the `check_ganglia.py` script as Nagios user?

Comment: I am yet to check that. However, I managed to get around this issue by installing NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor), where I am able to successfully run commands defined in it like `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_load`. But, and this is a different issue, I am not able to install more plugins. I have described the problem in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070470/how-do-i-get-a-custom-nagios-plugin-to-work-with-nrpe
If you don't mind, would you kindly have a look and guide me on how to install the `check_hadoop_namenode.pl` service?Thanks