# How do I get a custom Nagios plugin to work with NRPE?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, monitoring, nagios

I have a system with no internet access where I want to install some Nagios monitoring services/plugins. I installed NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor), and I can see commands defined in it, like `check_users`, `check_load`, `check_zombie_procs`, etc.

```
command[check_users]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
...
```

I am able to run the commands like so:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_load
```

This produces an output like:

```
OK - load average: 0.01, 0.13, 0.12|load1=0.010;15.000;30.000;0; load5=0.130;10.000;25.000;0; load15=0.120;5.000;20.000;0;
```

or

```
WARNING – load average per CPU: 0.06, 0.07, 0.07|load1=0.059;0.150;0.300;0; load5=0.069;0.100;0.250;0; load15=0.073;0.050;0.200;0;
```

Now, I want to define/configure/install some more services to monitor. I found a collection of services [here](https://github.com/harisekhon/nagios-plugins). So, say, I want to use the service defined here called `check_hadoop_namenode.pl`. How do I get it to work with NRPE?

I tried copying the file `check_hadoop_namenode.pl` into the same directory where other NRPE services are stored, i.e., `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins`. But it doesn't work:

`$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_hadoop_namenode.pl`

I figured this might be obvious because all other services in that directory are binaries, so I need a binary for `check_hadoop_namenode.pl` file as well. How do I make the binary for it?

I tried installing the plugins according to the description in the link. But it just tries to install some package dependencies, and throws error as it cannot access the internet (my system has no internet access, like I stated before). This error persists even when I install these dependencies manually in another system and copy them to the target system.

```
$ <In another system with internet access>
mkdir ~/repos
git clone https://github.com/harisekhon/nagios-plugins 
cd nagios-plugins 
sudo nano Makefile

# replace 'yum install' with 'yumdownloader --resolv --destdir ~/repos/'
# replace 'pip install' with 'pip download -d ~/repos/'
```

This downloaded 43 dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies, and so on) required to install the plugins.

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

`check_users`, `check_load` or `check_zombie_procs` are defined on the client side in `nrpe.cfg` file. Default location are `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg` or `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`. As I read, you already found that file, so you can move to next step.

Put something like this to your `nrpe.cfg`:

```
command[check_hadoop_namenode]=/path/to/your/custom/script/check_hadoop_namenode.pl -optional -arguments
```

Then you need restart NRPE deamon service on client. Something like `service nrpe restart`.
Just for you information, these custom script doesn't must to be binaries, you can even use simple bash script.

And finally after that, you can call the `check_hadoop_namenode` command from Nagios server or via local NRPE deamon:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_hadoop_namenode
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try these when I get back into the project and let you know if it worked.